# Prove that the function $f$ is a decreasing function.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For $n \geq 2, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t \geq 1$, prove that the function $f$ (with $t$ as the variable and $n$ as a parameter) is a decreasing function.
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{{8n{t^3}}}\left( { - 3n{t^4} + 2n{t^2} + \sqrt {32n{t^3}\left( {2nt + 3{t^3} + t} \right) + {{\left( {3{t^2} + 1} \right)}^2}{{\left( { - n{t^2} + n + {t^2} + 1} \right)}^2}}  + n + 3{t^4} + 4{t^2} + 1} \right)$$
I have verified that it indeed decreases for $n=2,3$. The proof seems quite cumbersome. I am looking for a more elegant approach.

This problem arises from another task I am working on, which involves finding optimal constants.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

We use Maple to simplify the expressions.

Let $g := f(t)$. It is easy to verify that $g > 0$, and
$$A(t) g^2 + B(t) g + C(t) = 0 \tag{1}$$
where
$A(t) := 64\,{n}^{2}{t}^{6}$, and $B(t) :=  48\,{n}^{2}{t}^{7}-48\,n{t}^{7}-32\,
{n}^{2}{t}^{5}-64\,n{t}^{5}-16\,{n}^{2}{t}^{3}-16\,n{t}^{3}$, and $C(t) := -
96\,n{t}^{6}-64\,{n}^{2}{t}^{4}-32\,n{t}^{4}
$.

Taking derivative on (1), we have
$$A'(t) g^2 + A(t) \cdot 2g g' + B'(t) g + B(t) g' + C'(t) = 0$$
or
$$(2g A(t) + B(t))g' = - \left( A'(t) g^2 + B'(t) g + C'(t)\right). \tag{2}$$

We have
$$2g A(t) + B(t) = 16nt^3 \sqrt {32n{t^3}( {2nt + 3{t^3} + t} ) + {{( {3{t^2} + 1} )}^2}{{( { - n{t^2} + n + {t^2} + 1} )}^2}},$$
and
\begin{align*}
 &A'(t) g^2 + B'(t) g + C'(t)\\
 ={}& \frac{6}{t}\Big(A(t) g^2 + B(t) g + C(t)\Big)\\
  &\quad + 16 n{t}^{2} ( 3n{t}^{4}-3{t}^{4}+2n{t}^{2}+4{t}^{2}+3n
 +3 ) g+64n{t}^{3} ( 2n+1 )\\[6pt]
 ={}& 16 n{t}^{2} ( 3n{t}^{4}-3{t}^{4}+2n{t}^{2}+4{t}^{2}+3n
 +3 ) g+64n{t}^{3} ( 2n+1 ).
\end{align*}

From (2), we have $g' < 0$.